# JSF & connection to Database : Good practises

Tags: java, database, jsf, jdbc, web

I am literally new to JSF and web Dev.

I am creating a website that interact with a database. I have understood how to display the data from a table but currently I am creating a new connection everytime I change the table to display.

Isn't it better to create the connection at the beginning and close it at the end ?

How should I share the connection informations between the different classes that are using it to query the DB ?

Comment: Try to use a framework like Spring for managing that. There are many examples on that if you will look

Comment: Enjoy creating a connection pool and gradually move to a (distributed) transaction management system like JTA.